# Return default INSERT INTO message from function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Looking to have the default INSERT INTO message where the count of records inserted is printed out. Know this has something to do with changing RETURNS from void to something else and possibly adding an OUT argument?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION etl(from_table regclass, to_table regclass) RETURNS void AS
$$
  BEGIN

  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || to_table || ' ('
      'title'
    ') '
    'SELECT '
      'data->>''title'' as title'
    'FROM ' || from_table || ' '
    USING from_table, to_table;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Print out the SQL *before* executing it.  The error will be obvious.  Hint:  think comma.

Comment: `returning` will return the actual values, not the count of rows affected

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, deleted a bunch of select statements to simplify the example and created a buggy statement, fixed now. Good eyes!

Comment: The `USING` clause is superfluous and should be remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` command to populate, then return a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION etl(from_table regclass, to_table regclass) RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE
    rows integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I (title) 
                        SELECT data->>''title'' as title
                        FROM %I', to_table, from_table);
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN rows;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You should also really use the `format()` function to assemble your dynamic SQL command. Also, you can write literal strings over multiple lines without having to use ending/opening quotes at every line.